# How to add a custom platform to Cordova or Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I develop cross platform HTML5 apps using Cordova and sometimes I need to deal with custom/proprietary devices like commercial smart TVs, set-top boxes.  So far for these devices I need to create non-cordova web apps using their SDK.

It would be ideal if I can create custom cordova platform plugin to bridge the gap so the app only needs to deal with cordova.  So I just need to:

`$ cordova platform add xxstb`

I searched all over and couldn't find any doc about creating a platform. The cloest I can get is the `browser` platform code on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser) and I have no idea what all the hooks are.

Any insight is appreicated.

Comment: the vendors of that devices should contribute with cordova team to add their platforms. Or you can try to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Apache cordova has released support for custom platforms in Cordova 7.0.0

`cordova platform add <custom-platform-name>`

see [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I can't seem to find any more details about creating a platform other than this platform add command.

Comment: yea, it does appear limited at this time. I think the've cracked the window for us but have not elaborated on how to go about using this feature.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentioned, custom platforms have been released as part of Cordova 7 and they can be installed like regular platforms.

You can find an example of a shell of a custom plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-test-platform). The documentation hasn't been added yet, but there is a pull request to add [details](https://github.com/audreyso/cordova-test-platform/blob/9c434eefac55ffb50f16b6be0f7a877a93970fe4/PlatformRequirements.md).